# Defining a partially typed Shape/Object

Tags: typescript, intellisense

Is there a way to define only a "part" of the object type, while having the rest of it essentially be "any" type? The goal main goal here is to have **intelliSense** support for the part that is defeined, but if types-checking support is included, all the better. To illustrate, lets first define one helper type:

```
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void
}[number] extends (x: infer U) => void
  ? U
  : never
```

It does what the name implies, now let's deal with the issue

```
type A = {
  A: { name: "Foo" }
}
type B = {
  B: { name: "Bar" }
}
    
type Collection<T extends any[]> = TupleToIntersection<{ [I in keyof T]: T[I] }>

declare const C: Collection<[A, B]>

C.A.name // "Foo" as expected
C.B.name // "Bar" as expected

declare const D: Collection<[A, any]>

D // <=== this is now of any type because obviously an intersection of any and type A gives back any
D.A.name // <=== So whilst this is technically still okay, there is no "intelliSense" support
```

Any way to achieve this?

One idea I had was to keep the type as "any" and then have a typeguard to force it into a type that I know the shape of, where I am using it in code, which I think is the way that tsc actually wants to keep it as a "typesafe" code, but this requires "unnecessary" defning of a typeguard as well as defining types where you need to use them instead of having them defined "for you" by the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection is similar to the mathematical set intersection, where the result of `A & B` are all elements from `A` and `B`.

`any` is a set that contains every possible value so intersecting with `any` will give `any` at the end:

```
// any
type Case1 = number & any;
// any
type Case2 = {a: string} & any;
```

To fix it you can replace `any` with `unknown`, which is similar to `any`, however, the compiler will give preference to the type from the other set:

```
// number
type Case1 = number & unknown
// {a: string}
type Case2 = {a: string} & unknown;
```

Testing:

```
declare const D: Collection<[A, unknown]>;

D; // A
D.A.name // "Foo"
```

But if you want to support something extra to be added to the type, which I encourage you to avoid, you can use something more specific rather than `any` or `unknown`. For instance, to support adding new fields to an object one can use `Record<string, any>`

Testing:

```
declare const D: Collection<[A, Record<string, any>]>;

D; // A & Record<string, any
D.A.name; // "Foo"
D.additional = ''; // no error
```

Comment: Problem there is D is not suppose to be of type `A`, its suppose to be sort of an "A + whatever else", so that you can do D.A.name, but also do D.TRALALA.name, essentially having "support" for the defined types, but accepting anything else as well. I am aware this could cause runtime errors

Comment: @Dellirium I think it won't be possible with either `any` or `unknown`. You can do something like this `Collection<[A, Record<string, any>]`

Comment: Perfect, its exactly what I wanted, update your answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1):

Does this approach work for you?

```js
/**
 * For some reason, TypeScript won't collapse string unions down to `string`
 * if they include it via `(string & {})`. This is a bit hacky, and I suspect
 * it may break in future versions of TypeScript.
 */
type StringWithAutocomplete<U extends string> = U | (string & {});

/**
 * This type defines your intellisense, excluding the catch-all `any` properties
 */
type BaseType = {
  A: number;
  B: string;
  C: boolean;
}

/**
 * For a given key, get its type in `BaseType` or otherwise resolve to `any`
 */
type KeyTypeOrAny<K extends StringWithAutocomplete<keyof BaseType>> =
  K extends keyof BaseType ?
    BaseType[K] :
    any;

/**
 * A mapped type that is functionally an intersection of `BaseType` and
 * `Record<string, any>`, but with type-checking on defined types and
 * intellisense.
 */
type AnyWithAutocomplete = {
  [key in StringWithAutocomplete<keyof BaseType>]: KeyTypeOrAny<key>;
};

const foo: AnyWithAutocomplete = {
  A: 3,
  B: 'string',
  C: true,
  D: 'undefined types can be anything'
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-3tEJ8WEQliUWdNhRRYsqHrA4jmbc5Lm+KI5UXdtulrLZ6MbY4sBbS4rjHTtJx7FclVzKgCyLEthMcd4rR3SAhAmThrDNJVaN4xiBOY6U2K1RVoAAZlIOVRSVPhdT4cytWNPRkEUEk5QAESs5QPBwvDkLodQaV0dUtyoSMtj4KBok1IA)

Just as an obligatory cautionary note, before I go into the details, be very careful with how you allow `any` to leak into your codebase. Any code that touches the `any` type is essentially opting out of TypeScript's type checking, so it's generally best avoided whenever possible.

---

As I've explained in the comments in the code example, this approach hinges on what I suspect is a rather hacky way in TypeScript to allow any string while retaining autocomplete.

Normally, any union of strings that includes `string`, for example `'A' | 'B' | string`, collapses down to just `string`. However, if you change that union to `'A' | 'B' | (string & {})` then TypeScript will not collapse the union, so it retains the individual strings while also allowing any string.

The `{}` type includes everything except for `null` or `undefined`. Essentially, everything in JavaScript on which properties can be accessed without throwing an error - `null` and `undefined` are the only exceptions to that. The built-in utility `NonNullable` type is actually implemented using an intersection with this `{}` type, and this is also why it's typically warned against by linters since it may look like it just means "any object".

Anyway, I've used this quirk to create a mapped type that has some specific properties, while also allowing any string property. By defining a type which associates those named properties with a type, while falling back to `any` for other properties, this lets us create a type that is essentially an intersection between a well-defined object type and `Record<string, any>`, without causing TypeScript to collapse that intersection to simply `any`. This means you get to keep your type checking and autocomplete, but also have the open-ended type you were looking for.

Comment: From what I understand this essentially uses the same concept to create an intersection of a type with a Record<string, any>, which allows for a partial type definition as I requested.  Albeit, here the base type has to be defined throughout all the type definitions which doesn't suit my needs, but check the other answer, a simple passing of "Record<string, any>" as one of the defined types worked well

Comment: Huh, I just assumed that an intersection with `Record<string, any>` wouldn't work without trying. That is much simpler. Oh well, this was fun to toy with at least

Comment: The (string & {}) hack is still very useful thing to know, it will be useful on some other occasion, im sure of it